# How do I compare an ADO field to the current time in ASP Classic/JavaScript?

Tags: sql-server, time, asp-classic, ado, jscript

My SQL Server database table has a `time(7)` field. I can access this table from an ASP script using the usual ADODB.Recordset methods. I want to then compare the time retrieved to the current time. I'm guessing this'll need a JavaScript Date object, since that's the language this version of ASP is using. Problem is, I'm having trouble finding a way to compare the ADO Field object to a JS Date.

Basically, I want to write a line like

```js
var pastTime = hasTimeComeYet(rs.Fields.Item("Time"));
```

but I don't know how to write the `hasTimeComeYet` function.

**EDIT:** I've cast the field to `datetime` (with appropriate modifications for date) as part of the SQL query. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with JScript, so I won't be able to use any functions that are only available in VBScript.

Comment: What about the `Date`, how do expect to compare a `Time` without the `Date`? First off you probably want to return `CONVERT(time(3), [time_column]) [time_column]` in the SQL to make sure you are passing the maximum precision that a JScript `Date` object can deal with *(milliseconds)*, you then want to utilise the `.setHours()`, `.setMinutes()`, `.setSeconds()` and `.setMilliseconds()` *(or the `setUTC...` time equivalents)* but honestly I can't see the comparison working without a `Date` part. Also what have you tried so far, no working shown currently?

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript? VBScript, this'd be easy - `Datediff("s",Now,rs.Fields.Item("Time"))` or something along those lines.

Comment: @Martha Would that work against a `time` field? Not tested it but not sure it will as it's missing the date part so `DateDiff()` will error. Which takes me back to the my previous comment *"I can't see the comparison working without a `Date` part"*.

Comment: @Lankymart: I think VBScript will supply the date parts... though you might have to do a `CDate`? Obviously, I haven't tested anything here...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the SQL Server query is returning an appropriate date/time data type, the Recordset will return a variant of subtype VT_DATE. In JScript, you can simply pass this value to the [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd9w2te4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) constructor and it will construct a JScript `Date` object.

```
var jsDateFromDB = new Date(rs.Fields.Item("theTime").Value);
```

A few notes about the example:

- I can't remember if the `.Value` is required or not. If JScript doesn't expand default properties, then you need the `.Value`, otherwise you're just getting the `Field` object and not the actual date value. I would put it just to be explicit in either case.
- I renamed the column to "theTime" only to avoid using a reserved name. I'm sure it's just an example name anyway.

I'm assuming that you know how to do the date comparison in JScript, or at least can easily look it up.